# how to make two selections in one

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, query-optimization

Hey guys i have 3 tables.

First table called `parceles`(fid, REFCAT)

Second table called `informacio`(fid, Ref_cadastral, fid_parceles)

Third table called `cedules`(fid, Ref_cadastral, fid_parceles)

fid_parceles is the foreing key from parceles in the two tables.

I use this select for show how many rows with n "REFCAT" have rows

```
SELECT p.REFCAT, count(i.Ref_cadastral) as Informacio 
from informacio i, parceles p 
where i.fid_parceles=p.fid 
group by p.REFCAT 
order by Informacio DESC
```

the same with the cedules table.

```
SELECT p.REFCAT, count(c.Ref_cadastral) as cedules 
from cedules c, parceles p 
where c.fid_parceles=p.fid 
group by p.REFCAT 
order by CEDULES DESC
```

The all selects work splitted but

How i can do this 2 selects in only one?

The result will be:

REFCAT |  INFORMACIO| CEDULES

Comment: Why do you use COUNT() by a column? Does `x.Ref_cadastral` can be NULL? PS. Use JOIN, not cartesian.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do it :

```
SELECT
    p.REFCAT,
    count(i.Ref_cadastral) as Informacio,
    count(c.Ref_cadastral) as cedules 
from parceles p 
left join informacio i on i.fid_parceles = p.fid
left join cedules c on c.fid_parceles=p.fid 
group by p.REFCAT
order by Informacio DESC , cedules desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I provide this option as it does not guarantee that a given REFCAT will always exist in both the Informacio and cedules sub-tables.  So by pre-querying each of them individually and grouped by the final REFCAT that DO exist, it will at-most return one record per REFCAT to the outer query.  Then, grabbed only distinct REFCAT values from parceles to prevent duplication.

By applying coalesce() to the POSSIBLE (via left join) secondary aggregate queries will prevent NULL values in your final output.

```
select
      p.REFCAT,
      coalesce( i2.Informacio, 0 ) Informacio,
      coalesce( c2.cedules, 0 ) cedules
   from
      ( select distinct p.REFCAT
           from parceles ) p
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select 
                 p2.REFCAT, 
                 count(i.Ref_cadastral) as Informacio 
              from 
                 informacio i
                    JOIN parceles p2
                       on i.fid_parceles = p2.fid 
              group by 
                 p2.REFCAT ) i2
           on p.REFCAT = i2.REFCAT
        LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT 
                p3.REFCAT, 
                count(c.Ref_cadastral) as cedules
             from 
                cedules c
                   JOIN parceles p3 
                      on c.fid_parceles = p3.fid
             group by 
                p3.REFCAT ) c2
           on p.REFCAT = c2.REFCAT
   order by
      coalesce( i2.Informacio, 0 ) DESC,
      coalesce( c2.cedules, 0 ) DESC
```